# Opening Google Maps from my Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I was wanting to be able to have a button which would launch the Google Maps app, however I cannot really seem to be able to get it to work, could I have some help? Really sorry if this seems easy, i'm still a newbie with android, below is my oncreate method with the relavent Intents

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_headphones);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    Button mapsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapbtn);

    mapsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

My app keeps crashing when the button is pressed, and the error i am receiving is

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: juddsafc.actionbarexample, PID: 2980
>       java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: f

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `%f,%f` you need to provide values afterwards... So change this:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f");
```

to this:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 35.6833, -139.7667);  // numbers are just some random coordinates
```

Comment: Oh shoot!, can't believe I missed that :(, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f");
```

The %f is a formatter. Your program expects a value to replace %f, but there's not enough arguments for your function to accomplish this.

You could do the following:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 100, 200);
```

And instead of using 100 and 200, you pass along the values you want to display.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! :), I can't belive I made that mistake :(